# перегрузка оператора +, конкатенация

Tags: c++, строки, fs

нужно выполнить конкатенацию 2 путей к папкам. У меня получается бесконечная рекурсия в строке с `return`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::string operator+(const fs::path &set_folder, const fs::path &user_path) {
    return set_folder + user_path;
}

int main() {

    const fs::path user_path = "C:\\Users\\ys\17";

    fs::path set_folder;

    std::cout << "введите set_folder :";
    std::cin >> set_folder;

    fs::path res;

    res = user_path + set_folder;

    std::cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не надо делать свой оператор. Используйте `user_path += set_folder;`, и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы определили сложение путей через сложение путей. Рекурсия.
Если определить через сложение строк, то рекурсии не будет:

```
std::string operator +(const fs::path &set_folder, const fs::path &user_path) {
    return set_folder.string() + user_path.string();
}
```

Ещё одна вещь. Программист вызывая `c = a + b` преполагает что у `c`, `a` и `b` одинаковый тип. В вашем случае это не так. Этот вариант более привычен:

```
fs::path operator +(const fs::path &set_folder, const fs::path &user_path) {
    return set_folder.native() + user_path.native();
}
```

*В примере выше мне подсказали что `native` лучше `string`.*

Тоже самое можно сделать не переходя к строкам. Тут я специально передал первый аргумент как копию, чтобы изменить его в функции:

```
fs::path operator +(fs::path set_folder, const fs::path &user_path) {
    set_folder += user_path;
    return set_folder;
}
```

И ещё одна вещь. `fs::path` поддерживает оператор `/` который объединяет пути. В отличие от простой конкатенации он добавляет разделитель, если это нужно. Обычно это нужно:

```
fs::path operator +(const fs::path &set_folder, const fs::path &user_path) {
    return set_folder / user_path;
}
```

Если вас устраивает как работает `/`, то оператор `+` не нужен:

```
// было res = user_path + set_folder;
// стало
res = user_path / set_folder;
```

Comment: Во втором варианте стоит использовать `.native()` вместо `.string()`, чтобы на винде не преобразовывать лишний раз пути в однобайтовую кодировку и обратно. Или еще лучше, использовать уже существующий `+=`...

Comment: *"Теперь ясно что оператор не нужен"* Не-а, он работает не так, как два ваших первых примера. В отличие от них, `/` всегда добавляет слеш между двумя путями (если его там раньше не было), в отличие от честного `+`.

Comment: Он добавляет разделитель только если тот необходим.

Comment: Да, но первые два варианта его не добавляют вообще никогда.

Comment: Тем первые варианты и плохи. :)

Comment: Иногда именно это и нужно. :) Непонятно, почему `+=` подвезли, а просто `+` нет...

Comment: Мне простая конкатенация кажется опасным занятием на путях. Хотите складывать как строки, так складывайте строки.